# Cron troubleshooting

Tags: magento-1.8, cron, extensions

I'm working on a magento community 1.8.0.1 shop. During the development of an extension, I noticed that other extensions with cron job configured weren't running when I hit cron.php.
I tried to troubleshoot the problem through magento files, but I got stuck in the `/lib/Varien/Profiler.php` file.

I tried to disable my current development (via configuration > system > advanced, and via xml file), checked php and magento error logs before going on debug through magento files, now i'm getting stuck, I don't know where to start to troubleshoot this issue. The cron worked like a charm for a long time, I just don't know why and when it stopped working.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The execution of `cron.php` does not necessarily trigger all cron jobs defined in the system. In the first place, it checks if there are any jobs scheduled to be run at that time.

So there is a chance that everything works as designed in your system. To check if the jobs that you expect to be run are just not scheduled currently, the [`Aoe_Scheduler`](http://fbrnc.net/blog/2011/03/magento-cron-scheduler) extension is a good starting point for troubleshooting.

Comment: Thanks for the advices, but there's several disfunctions on the development server of my website that indicates the cron isn't running anymore. Thanks for the extension, i got a message "No heartbeat task found. Check if cron is configured correctly." after installing it, but it's already helping me, i thought the issue was coming from my developments, but it might be something wrong with the global cron config. I'll dig this

Comment: aoe_scheduler just fixed it. after some configuration and some manual trigger of functions, cron just began to work again. I'm glad the extension fixed my issue, but i still don't know what the issue was, kinda frustrating. It looks a lot like a ghost bug, but i got real code disfunctions before installing aoe_scheduler, so i don't really know what to think